# Scalar product for duality - symbol and adjoint operator problem

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, harmonic-analysis

I am reading "An introduction to harmonic analysis" written by Y. Katznelson and I have a problem with understanding his symbol for scalar product of a functional and a function. This is my problem:

He define a homogeneous Banach space on $\mathbb{T}$ as a linear subspace $B$ of $L^1(\mathbb{ T})$ with a norm $\|\quad \|_B \geq \| \quad\| _ {L^1}$ under which it is a Banach space and having the following properties:

(H-1) If $f\in B$ and $\tau \in \mathbb{T},$ then $f_\tau \in \mathbb {B}$  and $\|f_\tau\|_B = \|f\|_B,$

(H-2) For all $f \in B \quad \lim_{\tau \to \tau_0} \|f_\tau - f_{\tau_0}\|_B = 0.$

After that, he introduces the Fourier coefficients of a functional $\mu \in B^*$  as a number
$\overline{\langle e^{int} , \mu \rangle}$(with assume that $e^{int} \in B$ for every $n \in \mathbb{Z}).$  This is unfamiliar to me, because in all books I have read from analysis I only seen scalar product with 
a functional on the first place. Somehow I figured out that must be $\langle f , \mu \rangle = \overline{\mu(\overline{f})},$ but that makes me a problem with proving that an adjoint operator( which is defined in this book as an operator which satisfy $\langle A f, \mu \rangle = \langle f, A^* \mu\rangle$) have the same norm as an operator $A: B \to B.$

Can someone show me where I am making a mistake?

Comment: Probably he is using that definition only in spaces where $||\overline{f} ||= ||f||.$ In that case, it is easy to prove that $||A|| = ||A^*||.$

Answer (score 0):

The author takes $\langle f,\mu\rangle$ as the value of $\mu(f)$ where $f\in B$ and $\mu\in B^\ast$. If we suppose $e^{int}\in B$, then we can define
$$
\hat\mu(n):=\overline{\langle e^{int},\mu\rangle}=\overline{\mu(e^{int})}\in\mathbb C.
$$
It is just a convention to express the value of a linear functional on an element. Probably the reason is to emphasize the duality of $B$ and $B^\ast$. Since you can either view
$ \mu(f) $ as the linear functional $\mu\in B^\ast$ evaluated at $f\in B$, or the linear functional $f\in B\hookrightarrow B^{\ast\ast}$ evaluated at $\mu\in B^\ast$ as long as we note that
$$
|\mu(f)|\le\|\mu\|_{B^\ast}\|f\|_B
$$
which implies that both $\mu$ and $f$ are bounded functionals.

Do not confuse this notation as the inner product in Hilbert spaces, though we also use $\langle x,y\rangle$ to denote the inner product of $x,y\in\mathcal H$ where $\mathcal H$ is a Hilbert space.

So it makes no sense to verify the norms are equal. $e^{int}$ and $\mu$ are just not in some Hilbert space at the same time.

Comment: In that case, a scalar product $\langle f,\mu \rangle$ will be $\mathbb{C}$-lineal over a second coordinate, but in his examples(after definition) that is not correct.